# AttributeError: module 'sys' has no attribute 'maxint'

Tags: python, python-3.x, sys

I'm trying to run the following code with Python 3.7:

```
import sys
print(sys.maxint)
```

but I get an error:

```
D:\Python3.7\python.exe "D:/PyCharm 2017.2.3/Workplace/maximizer.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:/PyCharm 2017.2.3/Workplace/maximizer.py", line 2, in <module>
    print(sys.maxint)
AttributeError: module 'sys' has no attribute 'maxint'
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: As the error message states, you're trying to access the `maxint` attribute of the `sys` module, but `sys` doesn't have an attribute named `maxint`. Maybe you meant `sys.maxsize`?

Answer (score 68):

In python3, `sys.maxint` changed to `sys.maxsize`.

Here are the values:

**Python2**

```
>>> sys.maxint
9223372036854775807
```

**Python3**

```
>>> sys.maxsize
9223372036854775807
```

On the same platform, the values match.  The value is typically `2**31 - 1` on a 32-bit platform and `2**63 - 1` on a 64-bit platform.

Replacing your call to `maxint` with `maxsize` will stop this particular Traceback.

Comment: Integer.MAX_INTEGER changed to sys.maxint. Then it changed to sys.maxsize. I am wondering what's next??

Answer (score 1):

You are running your code using python3, which does not have a sys.maxint. Python2, however, does. So run your code as

```
python2 "D:/PyCharm 2017.2.3/Workplace/maximizer.py"
```